# Ajax success, how to refresh response every minute

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am really confused by this few lines of code that should work in my opinion. Div is updating when using .html, but not when using custom script.

I have a couple files, index.php and test.php

index contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    // custom script that displays parsed info goes here, doesn't work
                    $("#div").html(data); // works and updates
                }
            });
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

test.php contains json string.

index.php displays, and updates the parsed info in a div just fine, however the script using the data populated by json doesn't refresh.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If working with firefox you might as well install firebug to track what's going on. It allows you to see if requests are sent and the content and response of each.

Comment: So the code in your question works, but there's another part to it that you didn't include that doesn't work?

Comment: thank you all for your answers. The script in question was actually the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to make sure the request is being successfully completed.  First double check your selector syntax matches the markup.  '#div' is looking for any element with id="div".  If that is correct make sure the request is getting processed.  Try putting an alert or debug statement in the success function.  If you don't get a popup use the firefox or chrome network monitor to see what is happening when the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval`, calls the function at regular intervals of time, your function may or may-not  execute completely , when you call the function using `setTimeout`, there is a chance for executing of code (completely). well In your question, I'm writing a self executing anonymous function with a function name as `request` and I'm gonna call it after every **`10000 milli seconds`**

```
$(function () {
    (function request() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#selector").html(data); // works and updates
            }
        });
         //calling the anonymous function after 10000 milli seconds
        setTimeout(request, 10000);  second
    })(); //self Executing anonymous function
});
```

Just give it a try =)