# Webpage AutoRefresh

Tags: javascript, html

1) I want to make a live score mobile app in which the updates for the app is retrieved from my website....which is stored in the form of text file
2) On the server I want to write a scripting file which will do the work of retrieving the live score from some RSS feed & convert it into the text file format I need for the app

Now the Q is I want to make this scripting file to be invoked after every 1 minute to update the live score....either server should invoke this file or is there any mechanism in which the file will invoke itself

Thanks

Comment: why use a text file for saving data? why not a databasE?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the javascript [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) method.  It allows you to invoke a javascript method on a timed interval.  You could use that javascript method + ajax to call back to the server.  Without knowing your back end technology, one can't get into specifics about what to do on the server, however.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this lovely little HTML snippet if you just want the page to refresh every x amount of seconds

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT='60; URL=index.php' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Serve the scores up in JSON format and simply use jQuery.getJSON to grab the data in the client.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

See these answers for examples:

[Reload AJAX data every X minutes/seconds, jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881934/reload-ajax-data-every-x-minutes-seconds-jquery)

[Ajax success, how to refresh response every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783230/ajax-success-how-to-refresh-response-every-minute)

Answer (score 0):

expanding a wee bit on Hacknightly's answer:

..with a bit more clarity for general consumption:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```